# DOS Batch Programming pSEXEC

Tags: batch-file, dos, psexec

I have a batch file, say A.bat
On execution, this A.bat will create another batch file, say remote.bat

If I manually copy the remote.bat to the remote machine then it works 100% perfect. However, if I use it as a part of psExec in my A.bat then it does not work at all. However, my A.bat while executing says..

```
Connecting to ABCDEF machine
Starting PsExec Server on ABCDEF machine
Copying C:\remote.bat on ABCDEF machine
Started C:\remote.bat ABCDEF machine with Process Id XXXX
```

However, it looks to me that the remote.bat file is not executed at all.

What I have inside remote.bat is..

```
net use \\DIR1\DIR2 password /user:Administrator 
XCOPY \\DIR1\DIR2\DIR3\DIR4\* c:\DIR3\DIR4\ /E
```

I do not see the DIR3\DIR4 getting created under C: of my remote machine at all. However, it works if I manually copy the remote.bat and execute it in my remote machine.

The command I use to call PsExec is

```
psexec \\MachineName -u Administrator -p pasword -d -c -f c:\remote.bat
```

Any advice? please?

Comment: DOS... whoooboy. I can't offer any advice to resolve the issue, but you might also try the question on superuser.com.  I'm not sure if your feedback would be better or worse there.

Comment: Voted to close and migrate to SuperUser. It just needs a few more votes. BTW, since your batch file works fine on the remote machine, it does look like your use of `psexec` is to blame here. Is the c:\remote.bat` in the `psexec` command referring to a copy *on* the remote machine?

Comment: @Joe: Okay if not DOS Batch Programming, what else would you suggest for executing tasks on remote machines that are on a VPN?

Comment: @Pavium: Yep, psExec's -c option says it should copy the c:\remote.bat to the remote machine and then execute it there.

Comment: I'm not saying you're 'doing it wrong' -- just that I have no advice to offer, and that SuperUser.com might also be a good place to get info.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The association of BAT files with CMD is in your local user profile. I'm not shure how the Shell handles it exactly, but calling psexec on a remote target won't invoke cmd to run your batch file.

Put `cmd.exe /c` in front of `remote.bat` like this instead :

```
psexec \\MachineName -u Administrator -p pasword -d -c -f cmd.exe /c c:\remote.bat
```

But you must get the file remote.bat across first. The whole thing would look like this :

```
net use \\MachineName\C$ password /user:Administrator 
XCOPY remote.bat \\MachineName\C$\remote.bat
psexec \\MachineName -u Administrator -p pasword -d -c -f cmd.exe /c c:\remote.bat
net use /delete \\MachineName\C$
```